# How to properly place an <hr> element?

Tags: html

I'm currently trying to place an `hr` break in between two div containers, but when I place the `hr` tag in between the two divs in my HTML, it ends up showing in the middle of the first div container.

My HTML currently looks like this:

```
            <div id = "updatestatus" class = "statuscontainer">
                <div class = "verticalalign">Update Status</div>
            </div>
            <hr width = 90%>

            <div id = "insertstatus" class = "statuscontainer">
                <form></form>
            </div>
```

As you can see, I put the `hr` tag in between my major two div containers. However, when I try viewing the HTML, the `hr` is clearly placed in the middle of my first div container. Unfortunately, I can't post an image to show what's happening because this is my first post.
Thanks! 
Edit: here's the CSS for the parent container for the two `div`s:

```
#statuscontainer{
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid black;
margin-top: 6em;
height:10em; width: 35em;
}
```

and the CSS for the two containers:

```
#updatestatus{
position: absolute;
top:0;
height: 2em; width: 35em;
border:1px solid black;
```

}

```
#insertstatus{
position:absolute;
top: 2em;
height:5.5em; width:35em;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: What does your CSS for the `div` elements look like (`statuscontainer` class, and the `updatestatus` and `insertstatus` ids)?

Comment: Your items are placed absolutely which takes them out of the normal flow. Remove the absolute positioning to fix your problem...

Comment: If I remove the absolute positioning, I'm not sure how to reformat the contents within the parent container because their positions shift.

Comment: use "position:relative" and offset with things like "margin", "padding" (or "top" and "left").

Comment: Thanks for your help! It does flow naturally now, except I have a strange padding between the two divs and the line which I want to remove - without any padding that I put in the CSS. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Nevermind, I removed all padding and borders with and now it's good!

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a problem in your CSS.

I just ran your html code and its fine.

Look in your CSS file for the styling regarding the `hr` element.

Also, please tidy up your HTML code when you post - you can use an online tool like http://www.dirtymarkup.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that you have something in your CSS that causes the misalignment. Perhaps trying floating the elements like so:

```
.statuscontainer {
float:left;
}

hr {
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try and do something else like adding another div and making it into a horizontal line that is more flexible e.g:

```
        <div id = "updatestatus" class = "statuscontainer">
            <div class = "verticalalign">Update Status</div>
        </div>

        <div id = "line">
        </div>

        <div id = "insertstatus" class = "statuscontainer">
            <form></form>
        </div>
```

Then on css you could do:

```
#line{
add a bottom border here and give it a width height and whatever you want, that will be your new horizontal line
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I looked a lot into that, but apparently it's frowned upon to have empty `div`s?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm a little rusty at HTML but I'm pretty sure that you can do that

Comment: Why would you place an empty div for a 1px border? Just put a bottom border on "#updatestatus" and add padding and margin to taste.

Comment: Never said that wasn't an option :)

Comment: I didn't place a bottom-border because I only wanted the line to span about 90% of the width, and from what I can tell that's not an option.